# Filter button should deselect when another filter is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filtering, ternary-operator

I have a several buttons to filter a selection of items in a table.

When the user selects a button, the corresponding items are highlighted.

I need to set it up so that when another filter button is selected, the previous filter selection is cleared.

I want it so only one filtered selection can be made at one time. I was going to add a reset button, but thought the user would expect to be able to switch between different filters without having to click on a reset button each time.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
export default class FilterIcon extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: false
    };
    this.filterItem = this.filterItem.bind(this);
  }

  filterItem(id) {
    this.state.active === true
      ? this.props.applyFilter(null)
      : this.props.applyFilter(id);
    this.setState({
      active: !this.state.active
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { id, label } = this.props;
    let boundfilterItem = this.filterItem.bind(this, id);

    return (
      <FilterLink href="#" className={id} onClick={boundfilterItem}>
        {this.state.active === true ? (
          <FilterImage src={Icons[id + "Active"]} id={id} />
        ) : (
          <FilterImage src={Icons[id]} id={id} />
        )}
      </FilterLink>
    );
  }
}
```

The parent component is set up like this:

```
export default class Header extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props)
 this.state = {
  isActive: false,
 }
 this.iconToggle = this.iconToggle.bind(this)
}

iconToggle() {
 this.setState({
  isActive: !this.state.isActive,
 })
}

render() {
 return (
   <FilterIcon
      id="1"
       applyFilter={this.props.applyFilter}
    />
    <FilterIcon
       id="2"
       applyFilter={this.props.applyFilter}
     />
     <FilterIcon
       id="3"
       applyFilter={this.props.applyFilter}
     />
   )
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In the parent component, where you are rendering these `FilterIcons` and passing them a `label` and a `id` and a method `applyFilter`, why aren't you also passing an additional prop `active`? Sibling components aren't talking directly to each other, so the way it is designed, although a `FilterIcons` is invoking `applyFilter` in the parent, its sibling `FilterIcons` do not have any knowledge of this invocation. However, if in the `applyFilter` method of the parent you update an array or object (probably side by side with the `label` and `id` data) containing data about which `FilterIcons` is `active` you should be good to go. Obviously, that `applyFilter` would need to do more than the `filterItem` method you currently have. It would need to find the previously `active` `FilterIcons` deactivate it and activate the new one.

Comment: Good point. I will update my question with what the parent component is doing.